# How to make composite key using foreign keys?

Tags: mysql

I have a primary key `CustomerNo` from a table and another primary key `ProductNo.` from another table. I want to use them as composite key in addition to a third column called `Date` in a third table called Order. So the idea is that in the Order table, I have a composite key that is `CustomerNo-ProductNo-Date`combined. The `Date` (as an individual column) may be duplicated in the table. However, the composite key combination will remain unique. How do I make this possible?

Comment: A foreign key can only reference 1 table.You should have foreign keys to validate customer ,product and possibly data but you can have a composite (non-unique key) on customer,product, date if you think that will help performance,

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm quite new to SQL. What if I make ProductNo. as a foreign key in the Customer table? Will I then be able to link CustomerNo (pk) and ProductNo (fk) from the Customer table as composite keys to the Order table? And if so, how do I combine it with the Date as well?

Comment: That's quite wrong there is no direct relationship between customer and product. orders on the other hand have a relationship to customers and products so I would expect FKs in orders to customer and product (2 of) but I would not expect an FK in customer or product to orders.

Comment: How do you intend to preserve uniqueness of this composite key if the same customer places two different orders for the same product on the same date? You've stated that the date could be the same but that the key would be unique, and I don't see how those two statements make sense together.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with P.Salmon that it seems your table structure is not ideal. Creating a custom composite key like this would hurt your search performance because it would not be a quick lookup of indexed keys (such as you might search for "all orders placed yesterday," "all orders this year by a particular customer," or even "which products is no one buying." For each of those searches you would have to parse out the proper information from the composite key, meaning not only would your SQL query return every result, but you'd also have to parse each result and determine whether item with key 0015053020200412124523 is part of customer 0530's order.

One alternative solution would be an `Orders` table that has individual references to `CustomerNo` and `ProductNo`, plus a field for date. You'd also want an autoincrement primary key on the table, then you could leverage the strength of SQL and indexes (indices?) for any queries.

MySQL doesn't directly support composite keys like some other database systems do, but in this case I don't think that's going to hurt you. At least, you haven't explained a reason why your system needs a composite key over foreign key relationships. You could fake a composite key by using a stored procedure to trigger the insert, or several other methods, but again I think that's going to really cause your database to be difficult to work with in the future and encourage you to re-think your database design.